# Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput uses too much CPU

Tags: c#, .net, process, autocad

I created an application to open the AutoCAD Core Console to write some commands to it. The problem is the idle CPU usage is 100% for a single thread. I have discovered that the RedirectStandardInput property, when set to true does this. When I set it to false, the idle CPU usage is 0.1%. What I need is to be able to write a command to the console and when everything is finished, the idle speed returns to 0.1% CPU usage. Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

```
            // Set up process
            coreprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/isolate";
            coreprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            coreprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            coreprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            coreprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            coreprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            coreprocess.StartInfo.FileName = installpath;
            
            // Start Process
            this.ConsoleStarted = coreprocess.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the following sections of code and everything works normally.

```
coreprocess.StandardInput.Close();
coreprocess.StandardInput.Dispose();
```

Comment: Tip: `Dispose()` on any type of `Stream` internally closes it, it's never necessary call Close() explicitly before Dispose().